# How to separate the y-axis title (ggplot) and place in a separate grid?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to attach several plots together. I have found the solution on how to align the plots using egg:ggarrange. This nicely takes care of main plots. But I would like to have the y.axis title of all plots to be aligned also. And I cannot do it through the usual suggestion of working with ggplot options, since everytime I run my scripts the range of the numbers would be different and cannot come up with a fixed range, therefore the location of the axis title change. I know it is possible to separate the legend and place in a separate grid, I was wondering if we could do the same thing with the axis?

I have created a simple sample code here.

```
# example created to explain my problem

gdf <- data.frame(a = runif(10,  0, 1),
              b = runif(10, 100, 1000),
              c= runif(10, 10000,100000),
              d= runif(10, 100000,1000000))


p1 <- ggplot(gdf, aes(a, b)) + geom_point() + ylab ("first")
p2 <- ggplot(gdf, aes(a, c)) + geom_point() + ylab ("Second")
p3 <- ggplot(gdf, aes(a, d)) + geom_point() + ylab ("third" )

egg::ggarrange(p1, p2, p3, ncol= 1, nrow = 3, heights=c(1, 1, 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cowplot::plot_grid` which has an align argument :

```
cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2, p3, align = "v", ncol = 1)
```

[image: plot with cowplot]

Answer (score 2):

if the gtables have the same structure egg is overkill, you could simply use rbind (the gtable version doesn't like unit.pmax for comparison so I use the gridExtra version),

```
pl <- lapply(list(p1,p2,p3), ggplotGrob)
pl <- Reduce(gridExtra::rbind.gtable, pl)
grid::grid.draw(pl)
```

[image]